# Update Set Not Adding Anything Into Field

Tags: sql, sql-update, teradata

I'm still getting to grips with SQL. I took a  bit of time and managed to construct the following query.

I then selected COUNT(*) WHERE activePU = 1 and the result was 0. I know that there should be many thousands.

I looked through the view and noticed that all the cells under activePU are blank.

Every record should have 0 or 1, there should not be empty ones. But they are all empty. Is it apparent why from my syntax?

I suspect that the problem is with my syntax since I'm  a little less experienced.

```
UPDATE rdmatblsandbox.TmpNIMSalesForceDB
SET activePU = 
                CASE WHEN
                (TmpNIMSalesForceDB.SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE > CURRENT_DATE OR TmpNIMSalesForceDB.SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE IS NOT NULL) AND
                TmpNIMSalesForceDB.SERVICE_ACTIVATION_DATE < CURRENT_DATE AND
                TmpNIMSalesForceDB.ROGERS_BILLING_SYSTEM IS NOT NULL
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the logic but the fact that you see blanks and not a 0 means perhaps it's not updating. Do you have a commit after this update? Or perhaps the field type is not numeric?  Can you also do a simpler test - just set activePU to 1 and see what happens?

Comment: well, `subscription_end_date > current_date or not null` is a bit suspect.  But I agree with @cardmagik,  your problem is likely procedural and not shown here.  When do you call that bit of SQL?

Comment: @cardmagik thanks for the feedback. I don;t know what a commit is? The field type is varchar(1). I created the new field about 10 minutes ago to hold 0/1 values. That wrong?

Comment: Sorry - commit may be an Oracle only term - I don't know Teradata.  Changes in Oracle are done in memory and only written to disk when committed with the Commit command.  What happens if you hardcode Set activePU = 1?

Comment: Hm. I hardcoded the field as 1, then selected count(*) where = 1 and the result was 0. Does this point to anything?

Comment: Perhaps try a Commit type command after your sql and then see what happens - I looked it up: In Teradata mode you use 'END TRANSACTION' to commit and 'ROLLBACK/ABORT' to rollback (the system automatically rolls back transactions upon an error though). Edit - In ANSI mode it works as always: COMMIT/ROLLBACK.  This is from http://forums.teradata.com/forum/general/use-of-commit-and-rollback-in-teradata

Comment: @cardmagik thanks for all the info. I'm a little lost in the terminology and am going to consult with one of my colleagues int he morning. I'll update this question when I find out what's happening. Thanks for all your help so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"The field type is varchar(1)"*

When it's a VarChar you should write a string and not a number, '0' and '1' instead of 0 and 1.

There's an automatic typecast from byteint to varchar which results in '  0' which is then silently truncated to ' '.

But why do you use VarChar(1)? There's a two byte overhead for VarChars, so you better go with a CHAR(1). Or use a BYTEINT or DECIMAL(1), both need a single byte for storage and you won't have problems with automatic typecasts...